# Minecraft specific chunks arent loading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

[image: The chunk]

This chunks stopped loading suddenly when I logged in my world. 
The problem is that chunk prevents my quarry from running properly and the ores to stop being processed. 
I tried to relog and do F3 + A and reset my render distance and it didn't help 
does any one have a suggestion what to do?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but what mod is this?

Comment: we need more info. like ram usage, f3 screenshot and pc specs.

Comment: @Shaeldon I beleive the jet pack comes from either the industrialcraft mod, or possibly the powersuit(?) mod. The quarry Ace is referring to comes from the buildcraft mod. All of these can be found in the Feed the Beast mod pack.

Comment: @Ace147258, what's in that chunk? (Like a chunk loader? Chests? A Tinkers' Construct Smeltery? A twilight portal? A PneumaticCraft pressure chamber? a ME chest-thing-setup? Just guessing..)

Comment: Also logs, chances are that chunk got corrupted and deleted. I see RP2 and BC so you are either using the retro pack or got project red.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, if the chunk was deleted/corrupted, that chunk would be full of air. That means the weird lighting shouldn't exist. There's a difference between an unloaded, empty/corrupted chunk. Also, corrupted chunks usually get regenerated... Empty chunks stay filled with air and unloaded chunks end up like what's shown in the picture.

Comment: @aytimothy unless no block update happened yet, place a new torch and see if it updates.

Comment: Well, we'll have to wait for the OP to try that... Because that always solves unloaded chunk problems... Most of the time. (Forcing; creating an update to load the chunk)

Comment: Your Ram is Failing to keep up.  Get out of there far enough to keep that area out of memory, exit completely.

Comment: @aytimothy It definitely looks like corrupted chunk https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-2545

Comment: What mods are you using?

Answer (score -1):

If you are reloading plugins this could be the cause. Some plugins do not handle reloading very well and require the server to restart. If that does not help unfortunately you'll need to start removing plugins 1 at a time to find which is causing the issue.

Comment: What does "reloading plugins" mean?

Comment: Reloading plugins means using an in-game command to reload your plugins like /reload

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I don't see anything in the question suggesting they're playing on a Bukkit server.